# hide the statusbar

Tags: iphone, statusbar

I hope to display the view of one of ViewControllers in my app as full screen , so in Interface Builder, I set the statusbar as None.
I also resize the frame of view as 320*480

but when I run the app, the view of the viewcontroller still displays the statusbar.

Welcome any comment

thanks

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call setStatusBarHidden:withAnimation: on [UIApplication sharedApplication].

Comment: `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:YES];`

Comment: even I use             
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES  animated:YES];

the statusbar disappeared, but there is a white block on the top of screen :-(

Comment: please refer to the white block on the image above

Answer (score 1):

it is not diffult to solve the problem. In your project setting plist file, check the key"Status bar is initially hidden", status bar will be removed from startup.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set your view controller's `wantsFullScreenLayout` to `YES`. Make your xib file as big as the screen and set this in your `viewDidLoad`.

> wantsFullScreenLayout
>
> A Boolean value indicating whether the view should underlap the status
>   bar.
>
> @property(nonatomic, assign) BOOL wantsFullScreenLayout
>
> Discussion
>
> When a view controller presents its view, it normally shrinks that
>   view so that its frame does not overlap the device’s status bar.
>   Setting this property to YES causes the view controller to size its
>   view so that it fills the entire screen, including the area under the
>   status bar. (Of course, for this to happen, the window hosting the
>   view controller must itself be sized to fill the entire screen,
>   including the area underneath the status bar.) You would typically set
>   this property to YES in cases where you have a translucent status bar
>   and want your view’s content to be visible behind that view.
>
> If this property is YES, the view is not resized in a way that would
>   cause it to underlap a tab bar but is resized to underlap translucent
>   toolbars. Regardless of the value of this property, navigation
>   controllers always allow views to underlap translucent navigation
>   bars.
>
> The default value of this property is NO, which causes the view to be
>   laid out so it does not underlap the status bar.
>
> Availability Available in iOS 3.0 and later.
>
> Declared In
>
> UIViewController.h