# Removing Info Bar in iPhone Interface

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4, interface-builder, xcode4

How do you get rid of the info bar displaying the battery, time, carrier, etc when running my app? Is it something I have to do using Objective-C, or is there an option within Interface Builder?

Comment: You can find the [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002679/hide-the-statusbar)

Comment: possible duplicate of [hide the statusbar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002679/hide-the-statusbar)

Comment: This solution is deprecated. animated: is not supported anymore. You have to give another parameter of the type UIStatusBarAnimation.

Comment: @Mats Stijlaart, that is what they say: setStatusBarHidden:<#(BOOL)hidden#> withAnimation:<#(UIStatusBarAnimation)animation#>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to your project info and add the key value:

Status bar initialy hidden. Set this on YES.

Or add this code to your app delegate:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
```

Comment: It is your xcode project. With the blue icon. Select it. Go to your target. Select the info tab. Right click in the properties table and Add Row.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to turn it off in both Interface Builder and in code. It's usually referred to as the "status bar" in Apple's documentation.

Comment: In the interface builder it is only a simulation, disabling the status bar there is used only for correct layout setup. But it is also possible to disable it with the Info.plist file and the boolean value with UIStatusBarHidden key.

Comment: I cannot find that option within my info file?